# Mixin returns a subclass of an abstract class, how do I specify the mixin's return type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mixins, typescript-generics

I have a mixin that is returning a concrete implementation of an abstract class. Everything fits together nicely until I try to extend the class returned by the mixin, at which point TypeScript complains that my new subclass doesn't implement the abstract methods.

I think I understand why this happens, but I can't find a way to inform the type system that I'm not returning the abstract class, I'm returning a concrete subclass.

#### Simplified Example

Here's a simplified example ([plaground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUoEsB2MwUAysQG64LBwDeAUHHGAK4BGSVzehAFOSiQtgALjhoYPAOYBKMeQi4AJnUZNEEfGghJgAOiQQp-QcJkBuNQF96N+qEixEqDHABiECDgJFSFKjSgRPhKmN6ExGRQlNSqTKwcXGA8MCZCouKSBLLyiioM6hpaOvqGxgAGbgDyVWIAJLQC6VblFta29Pbg0PDI6JgAQihQ4TBRMYEgwaHYKZH+sQXM7JwI3D5pwmIS0nJwCspx6gia2roGRrzlAwCCAEr1jabALW1MNnYOPXAobDsoCF6LkwAFlcCACEM0MAADwAFTgQWAITCcz80QCAD4jictJIWIDoLw1PEVlxoRjqGI4QAaEnLRJrfAoAC2GR22TgAF44AByG5-SQAmC8mR0OxMX7-QHrQgAOVZwF4ewOSksn26ThgAE8wDQAMKnfGEqDw7E8-DAADucF4entwykaDEKHw2oA2gBdMVc7FwyxdRzwABmLHwgNwmjgYIh+HhiKmyJmo3mlOAmN44wC+uBYkNeKgBJg0DNe3zOyLJZjkPQsLhmOxSz6rmr+Bz-QT01B4Jr0LNRyYuIrJt4FIm1O5cEtNqz1HbGGVNKnisnvNbooH6jQLD1UFHC2AS+ZbLe6gl6gSq1lMAVbOVuUOS0KMAAFrg0HoxwE9MkNq-33ox7AKe7ztGoUDADALBQPg0Y9m2wLqp0AD0yFwHKmgALRSkKMrNpgvIeBAACiICsmAui8nASgQMAmD4BA8C4CyFHAGyhBwAQL7ELgRAqDhUDCnAbIsmwxB8r+8qKlRwZQBALLOB2a7wVCsJESm6ITJivJ6DAaC8AATAArAAjEZMj0Ph7ieKR5G6J2SbdrGvDqWis7AeKKFoQA6tAADWaCWUacBsMMk7Trara8EMIwpO5MgyLwYZKMAwYEMAShLryMWipYoVQD+KS3kqbRAA)):

```js
export class PrinterService {
  public print(value: string): void {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

export class FooPrinterService extends PrinterService {
  public print(value: string): void {
    console.log(`FOO: ${value}`);
  }
}

export class BarPrintService extends PrinterService {
  public print(value: string): void {
    console.log(`BAR: ${value}`);
  }
}

export abstract class MixinBase<T extends PrinterService> {
  constructor(
    public service: T,
    public name: string = 'Abstract') {}

  abstract printName(): void;
}

export type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export function Mixin<T extends PrinterService>(ServiceClass: Constructor<T>): Constructor<MixinBase<T>> {
  class MixinClass extends MixinBase<T> {
    constructor(service: T = new ServiceClass(), name = 'Mixin') {
      super(service, name);
    }

    public printName(): void {
      this.service.print(this.name);
    }
  }

  return MixinClass;
}
```

If I try to extend from the mixin result which is what I want to be able to do):

```js
class FooExample extends Mixin(FooPrinterService) {}

// Non-abstract class 'FooExample' does not implement inherited abstract member
// 'printName' from class 'MixinBase<FooPrinterService>'.ts(2515)
```

Interestingly, if I instantiate the result directly, I get no complaints:

```
const bar = new (Mixin(BarPrintService))(undefined, 'Bar');
bar.printName();

// prints "BAR: bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the `Mixin` function in your example is `Constructor<MixinBase<T>>`. I.e. a constructor for `MixinBase`, not `MixinClass` as you would want. The function itself typechecks, as `MixinClass` is assignable to `MixinBase`, because it extends it.

But later `class FooExample extends Mixin(FooPrinterService) {}` "thinks" it's extending `MixinBase` and fails, as `MixinBase` is abstract, and, at least according to the types, `printName` is not implemented yet.

Modifying `Mixin` like so, and letting typescript infer the return type works:

```
export function Mixin<T extends PrinterService>(ServiceClass: Constructor<T>) {
  return class MixinClass extends MixinBase<T> {
    constructor(service: T = new ServiceClass(), name = 'Mixin') {
      super(service, name);
    }

    public printName(): void {
      this.service.print(this.name);
    }
  }
}
```

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5&module=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUoEsB2MwUAysQG64LBwDeAUHHGAK4BGSVzehAFOSiQtgALjhoYPAOYBKMeQi4AJnUZNEEfGghJgAOiQQp-QcJkBuNQF96N+qEixEqDHABiECDgJFSFKjSgRPhKmN6ExGRQlNSqTKwcXGA8MCZCouKSBLLyiioM6hpaOvqGxgAGbgDyVWIAJLQC6VblFta29Pbg0PDI6JgAQihQ4TBRMYEgwaHYKZH+sQXM7JwI3D5pwmIS0nJwCspx6gia2roGRrzlAwCCAEr1jabALW1MNnYOPXAobDsoCF6LkwAFlcCACEM0MAADwAFTgQWAITCcz80QCAD4jictJIWIDoLw1PEVlxoRjqGI4QAaEnLRJrfAoAC2GR22TgAF44AByG5-SQAmC8mR0OxMX7-QHrQgAOVZwF4ewOSksn26ThgAE8wDQAMKnfGEqDw7E8-DAADucF4entwykaDEKHw2oA2gBdMVc7FwyxdRzwABmLHwgNwmjgYIh+HhiKmyJmo3mlOAmN44wC+uBYkNeKgBJg0DNYqWUGAMBYUHwzn60fBBBz9aRKIbsahsLh2KWTFxOyLRIpE2p3LglptWeozYwypp48VY95MYIoqOhTQLD1UF4w4C8+ZbLe6gl6gSq1lMAVbOVuUOvfUMAAFrg0Ho99Q9MkNs-X3pD8Ax7vO0dgAPSgXAcqaAAtFKQoyn0ri8h4EAAKIgKyYC6LycBKBAwCYPgEDwLgLJYcAbKEHABBPsQuBECocFQMKcBsiybDEHy37yoqOHBlAEAsnWSErvgnYwihKbohMmK8noMBoLwABMACsACMKkyPQiGYCh6GYboCbTKCjb4LwklolOgHitpRpwMGnhjhO7iePpZG6Mq9AORAX4pNeSpaZ04FwAA6tAADWaC2XicBsMMTnWraom8EMIwpFZMgyLwYZKMAwYEMASjzryqWipYcVQL5Pj+cqlhAA))

The typescript handbook has a page on mixins here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
export type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export interface IBaseClass {
  propertyA: string;
}

export function mixins<T extends Constructor>(Base: T): Constructor<IBaseClass> & T {
  return class extends Base {
    propertyA: string;
  }
}
```

Basically create an interface of the inner class